# What are the lyrics of the song "Of Beren and Lúthien" in Sindarin?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkien-languages

*"The leaves were long,

The grass was green,

The hemlock-umbels tall and fair,

And in the glade a light was seen..."*

Does this song appear somewere written in Sindarin or Quenya? Did Tolkien write it? Did he not write it but someone else translated it?

I can't find any hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Tolkien never translated those words into any of his invented languages.

The only part of story of Beren and Luthien that Tolkien ever wrote in Sindarin was a couple of lines from the longer Ley of Lethien that Tolkien worked on in the 50s. (*The Lays of Beleriand* lines 99-103 of Canto III of the final version)

> Ir Ithil ammen Eruchín
> menel-vîr síla díriel
> si loth a galadh lasto dîn!
> A Hîr Annûn gilthoniel,
> le linnon im Tinúviel!

These lines were Luthien singing a song to Elbereth, and although Tolkien never provided a translation, several translations have been published by Tolkien linguists. (including [Patrick Wayne](https://dc.swosu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2718&context=mythlore), David Salo, [Glǽmscrafu](https://glaemscrafu.jrrvf.com/english/luthien.html), and
[Paul Strack](https://eldamo.org/content/words/word-3293589263.html))

> When the Moon, for us, the Children of Eru,
> a heavenly jewel shines silver, having watched.
> Here let flower and tree, listen in silence!
> O Lady of the West, Starkindler,
> to thee I sing, I Tinúviel!

### For the "Song of Beren and Luthien" as included in *The Lord of the Rings*, no official version exists in any of Tolkien's invented languages, but there have been some fan attempts at translating it into Sindarin.

Most notable is probably David Salo, who [translated the last half of the second to last stanza for the Peter Jackson films.](https://www.elvish.org/gwaith/movie_soundtrack_fotr.htm#lay)

> Tinúviel elvanui
> Elleth alfirin edhelhael,
> O hon ring finnil fuinui
> A renc gelebrin thiliol.

I have also found [this complete translation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwgqOSnQNMA) by Norman McLaren who renders the four lines you've quoted as:

> I *nimwaloth i bain a phant,
> I laiss in end calen nadhras,
> Calad egennir mi i lant
> E geil mi dhúath thiliol

Do note that both of those translations were made before much of what is now known about Sindarin was brought to light, and they are therefore very likely to have mistakes.